# prevent image from resizing the container

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, related-posts

im using the "related posts" plugin in WP but the thumbnail container resizes with the image like this: [image]

even though i set the width and height in pixels on the plugin settings like this:
[image]

i want to add a custom css to prevent the container from resizing and to stay fixed no matter the image size. i want all the thumbnail containers to be the same width and height. 
FYI the image comes from the posts featured image.

thanks!

> EDITED screenshot with 50px x 50px test

[image]

Comment: A link to the page might help.

Comment: its in my localhost

Comment: Have you tried to set thumbnail's width and height bit smaller? e.g. 50 x 50

Comment: @ChrisChen i just did. they get smaller but the height is still not fixed. the image aspect ratio controlls it. i want all sontainers to be the same size. heres a screenshot how they look as 150 x 150: http://i323.photobucket.com/albums/nn473/lilabajrami/Screen%20Shot%202017-02-21%20at%2000.57.49.png

Comment: I can not open the link, mind if you post a screenshot of your page in here @ 50 x 50 size?

Comment: Do you want the images to be cropped (cut off at the bottom), to always be the same height (no matter the width) or to have a fixed height _and_ width? The latter means they would be stretched.

Comment: @MrLister well, i want the images to fit maybe. not sure about that i think i can fix it but i dont want the image to change the height or the width of the container. i knew i could achieve this by inserting fixed size in pixels (and not in %) but it didnt happen with this plugin even though i set it to pixels (see the screenshot above)

Comment: @MrLister this is the plugin im using: https://webberzone.com/plugins/contextual-related-posts/

Comment: Is this a new install of CRP? If so, it won't automatically crop your old thumbnails. Best option is to install OTF Regenerate Thumbnails - https://wordpress.org/plugins/otf-regenerate-thumbnails/